# While checking the !password and !data condition, only the !password condition works and !data fails

Tags: node.js, mongoose, crud, mongoose-schema, bcrypt

I am trying to check if I am getting data and if the password is correct.

The password's condition is working fine, I.e I am getting an error when the password is incorrect.

But the !found condition is not running and the browser is loading continuously, instead of displaying, "Incorrect username or password".

I want both !found and !passwordOK condition must work. But in my case if the found value is null also, the browser, instead of displaying the error message, loading without stopping.

**Many Many thanks in advance**

```
**Router.post('/', async(req, res) => {

    try{

        const loginData = {
            email : req.body.email,
            password : req.body.password
        }

        const found = await DB_Collection.findOne({email : loginData.email})

        // comparing the password

        const passwordOK = await bcrypt.compare(loginData.password, found.password)

        if( !found || !passwordOK){
            res.send("Inncorrect email or password..!");
        }
        else{
            res.send("Logged in successfully...!");
        }

    }catch(err){
        return err
    }
})**
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a TypeError: accessing property of null here

```
const passwordOK = await bcrypt.compare(loginData.password, found.password)
```

found is null, after all. And it gets caught here:

```
} catch(err) {
    return err
}
```

Perform the check only if `found` isn't null. For example, like this:

```
const passwordOK = found 
    ? await bcrypt.compare(loginData.password, found.password)
    : false;
```

Comment: No such error I am getting.

It's just !passwordOK condition is working fine, but not the !found condtion.

I found out that, way before writing the bcrypt.compare code. !found condition was working fine.

Comment: I think he is write to test it please in the catch block do a res.send("catch block")
Or use your debugger ;\